# Noise on GIF exported from After Effects

Tags: gif, adobe-after-effects

I've run into this issue more than once and haven't figured it out yet - I made a few projects in Adobe After Effects then exported GIFs through Adobe Media Encoder, and they turned out looking like this:

[image]

or this: 
[image]

What are those dots and how can I remove them? 
Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.png-8 bit` and .`gif` both support 256 colours total. You're choosing colours outside their gamut, and so you're getting dithering as the exporter tries to match your colour - you can set different *kinds* of dither, and may find that "diffusion" is more random and therefor a bit less noticeable - or you could stick to colours within the 8-bit colour 256 tones gamut and skip this issue entirely.

If you limit your choices to one of these, your `.gif` will not need to dither:

[image]

***Note:***
`.gif`s ***can*** technically include *considerably more* colours than the basic 256 you get from 8-bit (8x8x8) by *both* customising the `gif` colour palette ***and*** setting separate colour blocks in the `.gif` (you can set up a `.gif` to allow each colour block to support its own unique custom palette) but that's typically way beyond the scope of a simple exporter interface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi GerardFalla! Thank you for your explanation! I think I have a rough idea about what's happening, although I will have to research more about 'dithering' to catch up!